# ARCore how to record the screen of the Android phone for photos & videos & save to mobile using Unreal?

Tags: android, video, camera, unreal-engine4, arcore

Please point me in the right direction if this question has been asked already. I'm coming from a Unity background & our current developer is more familiar with C++ in Unreal.

We have built an AR app using Google's ARCore & the helloUnreal sample as a starting point. We want to be able to record a video of the AR object through the camera - as you would usually record a video - & save this to the Android mobile's Photos or Gallery. We can get a photo saved - although we're still trying to work out where they're saved - help with this too? - but need to be able to both record & save a video. Maybe we can do it through recording the mobile screen somehow?

Any ideas without needing to go through Android Studio & in Unreal directly?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: If anyone has any ideas, they'd be more than welcomed! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a look at this documentation. It's about using WebCams but, it should work the same as a mobile camera. Never tried it on mobile before though.

https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Engine/MediaFramework/HowTo/UsingWebCams

Comment: Thank you for this @Dtb49! This would work in terms of accessing the camera, but saving the video file...?